# how can i keep in my listView item when i add a new item?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-recyclerview

I want to keep watching my item in the same place, when I add a new item to the list the item down, what can i do?

I am using firebase for this but that is not the problem.

Here, the item that i want to see

[image: here, the item that i want to see]

here, the new item that sends me down

[image: here, the new item that sends me down]

//this way I add my items from the MainClass

```
 if (o instanceof Post) {
        posts.add((Post) o);
        listaFeed.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }




public class ListaFeed extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Post> posts;
private Context context;

public ListaFeed(ArrayList<Post> posts, Context context) {
    this.posts = posts;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return posts.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {


    return posts.get(position-getCount()-1);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

{
    if (convertView==null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.card_feed, null);}

    Post post = (Post) getItem(position);
    ImageView foto = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_foto);
    TextView titulo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_titulo);
    TextView autor = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_autor);
    TextView modo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_modo);

    Picasso.with(context).load(post.getFoto()).into(foto);
    titulo.setText(post.getTitulo());
    autor.setText(post.getAutor());
    modo.setText(post.getModo());



    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Adding new item at 0th position in arraylist would solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the old item at the first position (that's how I understood the question) then you just need to add your new item at the correct position. Index should be 1 + position of the previous item.

Also I would recommend that you use RecyclerView instead of ListView for better performance. Use notifyItemInserted() instead of notifyDataSetChanged(), because it's not needed to reload and redraw everything when you insert one single item.

Comment: Thaks!!!  I used RecyclerView and added the item in position 0 like you told me  and it worked <3

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Could you please accept the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an array then fix your particular item position on the 0th index and add all item with respective index.

Comment: but the item would be added below, I need it up but do not send me down, or there is the possibility that I show only 10 items for example and I can see more if I keep going up or going down? i want something like facebook or instagram

Comment: fixed first item then it will may help